# LiveCycle table growing out of control

Tags: adobe, livecycle

Product: LiveCycle V. 2.5
Database: SQL Server 2008
OS: Windows 2008R2
Host: jBoss 4.2

I am submitting files to the watch folder service to compose PDFs through DDX. The process runs fine but I am now getting errors that the table EDCATTRIBUTEVALUEENTITY is out of space, and when I went to check the database is around 300GB. I am not storing any documents in the database as far as I know.

How should I go about purging that table? I tried the purge tool but all my jobs have the status of "11" which according to the documentation isn't even a valid status.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's the edcattributevalueentity table that's eating up all of the space?  Is your GDS stored in the database?

You might want to take a look at http://michael.omnicypher.com/2013/03/livecycle-gds-demystified.html to ensure that it's not the GDS growing out of control.

Let us know how you make out with that article to start.

Comment: thank you so very much for your answer. Unfortunately it isn't the GDS, I don't have it configure to store documents in the DB (I got an earful about that before). However, I am running a lot of file drop DDX and LiveCycle is not cleaning up and I don't know why. However, out of the horse's mouth - support sent me this - DELETE FROM LiveCycle.EDCATTRIBUTEVALUEENTITY WHERE confighandle NOT IN (SELECT id FROM LiveCycle.EDCCONFIGURATIONENTITY);